# Z-Transform Solving

Tags: z-transform

i was trying to solve this exercise with Z-Transform:

$   \begin{cases}
   x(n+2)-x(n+1)=a(n) & n\ge0 \\ x(0)=x(1)=0
   \end{cases}  $

where:

$ a(n)=\begin{cases}
   n^2-n & n & even \\ n^2+n & n & odd
   \end{cases}
$

I usually solve them using the geometric series of $ w $, that converges in
$\frac{1}{1-w} $ , but i can't manage to solve it.

Comment: For more help using the "Z-transform" (engineering terminology), also see the "generating function" (mathematics terminology).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have

$$a[n] = \left(n^2 - (-1)^{n}n\right)u[n]\text{*}$$ and the property $$\mathcal{Z}\left(x[n+k]\right)(z) = z^{k}\cdot\mathcal{Z}\left(x[n]\right)(z) -\sum \limits_{i=0}^{k-1}z^{k-i}x[i].$$

Hence,

$$\mathcal{Z}\left(x[n+2] - x[n+1]\right)(z) = \mathcal{Z}\left(a[n]\right)(z) $$$$\implies  z^2 \mathcal{Z}\left(x[n]\right)(z) -z^2x[0] -zx[1] -z \mathcal{Z}\left(x[n]\right)(z) +zx[0] = \mathcal{Z}\left(n^2u[n]\right)(z) - \mathcal{Z}\left((-1)^nnu[n]\right)(z) $$$$\implies (z^2-z) \mathcal{Z}\left(x[n]\right)(z) = \frac{z^{-1}(1+z^{-1})}{(1-z^{-1})^3} + \frac{z^{-1}}{(1+z^{-1})^2}, |z| > 1 $$$$\implies \mathcal{Z}\left(x[n]\right)(z) = \frac{2z(z^2+3)}{(z-1)^4(z+1)^2}, |z| > 1.$$ You can solve this by using partial fraction method and a table of $Z$- Transform pairs.

*$u[n]$ is the step function.

Comment: While i was trying to solve it by myself, i thought that Z(n*a(n))=-d/dz(Z(a(n)). Did you calculate these transforms this way?

Comment: @EagleOne, for $a(n)$, I have just used a table of $Z$-Transforms. In practice, it is what we do.

Comment: @AlexSilva : one can indeed derivate on the Z domain, see eg http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-transform#Properties

Comment: @leonbloy, Yes! You're right! We can use this property for computing the $Z$- transform of $a[n]$, but I think this is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Just a hint (but I'm not sure if this is easier than AlexSilva's answer): Consider $b[n]=a[n]-a[n-1]$. Then

$$b[n]= \cases{ 0& if $n$ is even 
\\4 n-2 & if $n$ is odd
}$$

(you can also assume that it's zero for negative $n$). Then you can obtain $B(z)$ (knowing the transform of $u[n]$ and $n u[n]$), by a composition with the decimation operator and shifting). And $X(Z) (z^2-z) = A(z)$ and $B(z)= A(z) [1-z^{-1}]$